# Difference between objects in views in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json

does anybody know the difference between the object on the initial `show.html.erb` in Rails and the `index.html.erb`? The reason I'm asking is because I'm using the javascript library d3.js and for that I need a json-object. In all `index.html.erb` I can create them with calling:
`<% @commits.to_json %>` but if I try to use that statement in any `show.html.erb` the browser tells me that the result is just an object (seems not to be a json) so that I later can't call `forEach` (that I need to call).

Thanks in advance!

Ok, for a better understanding I append more code:

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>

d3.json('<% @commit.jobs.to_json %>', 
            function(data){


      var margin = {top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 50},
          width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
          height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

      var format = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ");

      //parse time format correct
      data.forEach(function(d) {
          console.log(d.finished_at);
          d.finished_at = format.parse(d.finished_at);
          console.log(d.finished_at);
        });

   //more code!     


<% end %>
```

The problem is, I have a commit object in `show.html.erb` that has belonging jobs and now I want to visualize the belonging jobs with `d3.js`. I tested if this: `@commit.jobs.to_json` creates a valid json and it does! But the console throws an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'forEach'`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I assume the `@commits` variables is a collection of Commit objects. In the 'show' action, you usually want to manipulate (render) only one object, `@commit`. Make sure your object Commit has a `to_json` method to render itself as a JSON object.

Comment: Also if you always do forEach then do [@commit].to_json in show, so that you still have an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In show you usually have only one `@commit` that you are showing.

In index you usually have all `@commits` as an array of objects.

```
def index
   @commits = Commit.all # all
end

def show
   @commit = Commit.find(params[:id]) # only one
end
```

if you want all commits in the `show.html.erb` do `<%= Commit.all.to_json %>`

So there are technically no differences between the objects based on the view they are in.  They just mean different (`@commit`,`@commits`) things based on how they got initialized in the method before calling the view.

Comment: That's not the problem. I understand the system. I cannot call all commits in the `show.html.erb` because I have a association there so that I just need the belonging ones.

Comment: I added more code to my question for a better understanding what I mean!

Comment: The isse has been solved - you were right at some point. I need to declare the right json in the controller and return there the object with the association and not try to create the association in the view. Thanks for help - even it was not the really right answer I upvote it!